# How to authenticate an XML request in Tally for Password Protected Company

Tags: tally

To make an xml request from a password protected company in Tally, first we have to open the company in tally then we can only get successful response from Tally.

Is there any way around, so we can send password along with company name in xml request to authenticate without opening the company in the Tally?

Comment: as of now not possible